# Cannot use append(*pairs, Pair literal) (type Pairs) as type *Pairs in assignment

Tags: go

I'm writing a code to handle the combination of `warehouse[item[batch, qty]]` then group the `[batch, qty]` based on `batch` with sum of `qty`. my code is:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

type Inventory struct {   //instead of: map[string]map[string]Pairs
    Warehouse string
    Item      string
    Batches   Pairs
} 
type Pairs []Pair
type Pair struct {
    Key   string
    Value float64
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, 世界")
    var inventory = Inventory{} // or: new(Inventory) noth are working //warehouse[item[batch, qty]]
    inventory.Warehouse = "DMM"
    inventory.Item = "Helmet"
    inventory.Batches = append(inventory.Batches, Pair{"Jan", 10})
    inventory.Batches = append(inventory.Batches, Pair{"Jan", 30})
    inventory.Batches = append(inventory.Batches, Pair{"Feb", 30})
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", inventory)
    inventory.Batches.group()
}

func (p *Pairs) group() {
    sum := make(map[string]float64)
    pairs := new(Pairs)
    for _, el := range *p {
        sum[el.Key] = sum[el.Key] + el.Value
    }
    fmt.Printf("%v %T\n", sum, sum)
    for k, v := range sum {
        pairs = append(*pairs, Pair{k, v})     // <--------------- here is the error
    }
    fmt.Printf("%v %T\n", pairs, pairs)
}
```

But I got the mentioned error while grouping:

```
# _/C_/Users/HASAN~1.YOU/AppData/Local/Temp/present-048467841
.\prog.go:36:9: cannot use append(*pairs, Pair literal) (type Pairs) as type *Pairs in assignment

Program exited: exit status 2
```

Comment: you forgot to dereference `pairs`. Why are you using a pointer in the first place?

Comment: `pairs := new(Pairs)`. Here pairs is of type *Pairs. append takes a slice as first argument. You can instead do `var pairs Pairs` and then `pairs = append(pairs, Pair{k, v})`

new(Type) always gives a *Type. Read more [here](https://golang.org/src/builtin/builtin.go?h=new#L194)

Comment: @JimB with `pairs = append(pairs, Pair{k, v})` I got `first argument to append must be slice; have *Pairs`

Comment: Thanks @poWar for the explanation, it is working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tanks for the comments, there are 2 potential answers:

1. Define `pairs` as `var pairs Pairs` which is defining `Pairs` instead of `pairs := new(Pairs)` which is defining `*Pairs`
2. Dereference `pairs` at both sides of the assignment to be: `*pairs = append(*pairs, Pair{k, v})`

So the full working code for me now is:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

type Inventory struct { //instead of: map[string]map[string]Pairs
    Warehouse string
    Item      string
    Batches   Pairs
}
type Pairs []Pair
type Pair struct {
    Key   string
    Value float64
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, 世界")
    var inventory = Inventory{} // or: new(Inventory) noth are working //warehouse[item[batch, qty]]
    inventory.Warehouse = "DMM"
    inventory.Item = "Helmet"
    inventory.Batches = append(inventory.Batches, Pair{"Jan", 10})
    inventory.Batches = append(inventory.Batches, Pair{"Jan", 30})
    inventory.Batches = append(inventory.Batches, Pair{"Feb", 30})
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", inventory)
    result := inventory.Batches.group()
    fmt.Printf("%v %T\n", result, result)
}

func (p *Pairs) group() Pairs {
    sum := make(map[string]float64)
    pairs := new(Pairs)
    // var pairs Pairs
    for _, el := range *p {
        sum[el.Key] = sum[el.Key] + el.Value
    }
    for k, v := range sum {
        *pairs = append(*pairs, Pair{k, v}) // with pairs := new(Pairs)
        // pairs = append(pairs, Pair{k, v})   // var pairs Pairs
    }
    return *pairs
}
```

And the output is:

```
Hello, 世界
{DMM Helmet [{Jan 10} {Jan 30} {Feb 30}]}
[{Jan 40} {Feb 30}] main.Pairs

Program exited.
```